# Regular expression to find filename.extension

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression to find a `filename.extension` inside this:

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"VID_20120826_181852.3gp\"\r\nContent-Type: video/mp4\r\nContent-Transfer
```

I need to find `VID_20120826_181852.3gp`, now I have

EDIT with my code:

```
// Look for filename                    
string cadenaBusca = @"(?<=filename=\\"")\[^\\]+";
re = new Regex(cadenaBusca);
Match filenameMatch = re.Match(content);
```

But this doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried this=>http://txt2re.com/

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the backslash, try this regex:

```
(?<=filename\=\\")[^\\]+
```

Comment: I don't understand. You are trying something different than i suggested. See http://regexhero.net/tester/?id=64ef0a75-668f-428a-98da-93fbbc8b56f3

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
string cadenaBusca = @"filename\=\"(?<fex>\w\W+)\"";
re = new Regex(cadenaBusca);
Match filenameMatch = re.Match(content);
string nameAndEx=filenameMatch.Groups["fex"];
```

Comment: `\w\W+` matches a word character followed by one or more non-word characters.  That isn't really what you meant, is it?